# Web Scraping 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-lab

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=drama&groups=top_250&sort=user_rating,desc')

s=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
type(s)
d=s.find('div', {'id':'main'})
a_tag=d.find_all('a')
type(a_tag)

rows=[]
url_px='https://www.imdb.com'
for e in a_tag:
    Pic=e.find('img')
    title=Pic['alt']
```

This code is returning the "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error when I run

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-31926498d307> in <module>
      3 for e in a_tag:
      4     Pic=e.find('img')
----> 5     title=Pic['alt']
      6     src=url_px+Pic['src']
      7     img_html=f'<img src="{src}" />'

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

this massage was shown after I run

Comment: `Pic` is `None` - your `find()` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

try to comment out everything in your for loop and print the `e` then you can see what `e` is returning.

You should check if `PIC` is not `None`

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=drama&groups=top_250&sort=user_rating,desc')

s=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
d=s.find('div', {'id':'main'})
a_tag=d.find_all('a')

rows=[]
url_px='https://www.imdb.com'
for e in a_tag:
    Pic=e.find('img')
    if Pic:
        title=Pic['alt']
        print(title)
```